# Html Agility Pack C#

Tags: c#, .net, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

Eu gostaria de saber como funciona a `//` no Html Agility Pack. Bom, a duvida é a seguinte, código:

```
var t = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@class='" + attr + "']").First().SelectNodes("tbody").First()
                    .SelectNodes("tr");

int index = 0;

Empresa empresa = new Empresa();

foreach (var elem in t)
{
    var tdList = elem.SelectNodes("td");
    foreach (var td in tdList)
    {
        if (td.HasClass("higher"))
        {
            index++;
            empresa = new Empresa();
            empresa.nome = td.InnerText.Trim();
        }
        else if (td.HasClass("strong"))
        {
            empresa.nro = index;
            Siglas sigla = new Siglas();
            sigla.Sigla = td.InnerText.Trim();
            sigla.link = td.SelectNodes("a").First().GetAttributeValue("href", "");
            empresa.siglas.Add(sigla);
        }

        if (td == tdList.Last())
            listEmpresa.Add(empresa);
    }
}
```

Na parte de que eu estou pegando a table, se eu colocar

(Sem as `//`)

```
htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("table[@class='" + attr + "']").First()
```

Ele não traz objeto nenhum para minha lista, até ai ok, entendi que ai as `//` são necessárias.

Já na parte que eu tento pegar o href da tag `a`

(Com `//`)

```
sigla.link = td.SelectNodes("//a").First().GetAttributeValue("href", "");
```

exemplo de link pego = "www.google.com.br"

(Sem `//`)

```
sigla.link = td.SelectNodes("a").First().GetAttributeValue("href", "");
```

exemplo de link pego = "www.google.com.br/xxxx-xxxx"

Bom, a minha duvida é a seguinte. Por qual motivo que eu consigo pegar o endereço completo do href somente se eu utilizar sem as `//` ? Como funciona as `//` nessa biblioteca? Já vi também `.//` que também não sei direito como funciona. Consegui fazer o que eu queria que era buscar o endereço completo da tag "a", porém gostaria de entender o que eu fiz.

Answer (score -1):

Ola..
O Xpath e uma query language para selecionar facilmente nodes em linguagem de marcacao como por exemplo o proprio xml.

Segue um descritivo da linguagem que pode te ajudar a entender mais.
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_xpath.asp

uma boa ferramenta baseada no HAP para testar/descobrir os caminhos Xpath que o proprio HAP vai entender:
https://github.com/samfisher83/HTML-Agility-xpath-finder

Comment: Melhore essa resposta pois está bem tosca. Explique para o Autor da Resposta o que ele está usando e mostre as evidências. Ele não sabe que está usando XPath. Mostre o significado do que ele está fazendo assim como o significado do que ele tentou fazer. Lembrado a dúvida do autor :"Por qual motivo que eu consigo pegar o endereço completo do href somente se eu utilizar sem as // ? Como funciona as // nessa biblioteca? Já vi também .// que também não sei direito como funciona. Consegui fazer o que eu queria que era buscar o endereço completo da tag "a", porém gostaria de entender o que eu fiz."